# React: Navbar is not changing after token is passed to localstorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, navbar

I wrote a navbar component, created 2 const functions in order to display them according to appearance of 'usertoken' in localstorage. After login in with correct data i am receiving usertoken and it is being saved in localstorage. However, it does not rerender navbar instantly after usertoken is placed in localstorage. When i refresh page it is rerendered.

I have loginForm connected to Redux state.

**Navbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import './Navbar.css'

class Navbar extends Component {

 logOutHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
  this.props.history.push('/login')
 }

 render() {
  const loginRegistrationLink = (
   <ul className='navbar-navigation-dynamic'>
    <li className='navbar-navigation-item'>
      <Link to='/login' className='navbar-navigation-link'>
        Login
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li className='navbar-navigation-item'>
      <Link to='/register' className='navbar-navigation-link'>
        Register
      </Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
)
const profileLink = (
  <ul className='navbar-navigation-dynamic'>
    <li className='navbar-navigation-item'>
      <Link to='/profile' className='navbar-navigation-link'>
        Account
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li className='navbar-navigation-item'>
      <a href='#' onClick={this.logOutHandler.bind(this)} className='navbar-navigation-link'>
        Logout
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
)

return (
  <div className='navbar'>
    <ul className="navbar-navigation">
      <li className="navbar-navigation-item">
        <Link to='/' className='navbar-navigation-link'>
          Home
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {localStorage.usertoken ? profileLink : loginRegistrationLink}
  </div>
  )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 user: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(withRouter(Navbar));
```

**onSubmitHandler in LoginForm.js**

```
  onSubmitHandler = (e) => {

const { user_name, password } = this.state

      const loggedUser = {
      user_name: user_name,
      password: password
    }
    this.props.loginUser(loggedUser);

    this.setState({
      user_name: '',
      password: ''
    })
  this.props.history.push('/')
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

**loginUser action**

```
export const loginUser = user => dispatch => {
 axios.post('https://damianlibrary.herokuapp.com/users/login', user)
  .then(res => dispatch({
   type: LOGIN_USER,
   payload: localStorage.setItem('usertoken', res.data)
 }))
}
```

**authReducer.js**

```
import { LOGIN_USER, REGISTER_USER } from '../actions/types';

const authState = {
 users: [],
 status: ''
}

export default function(state = authState, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
  case LOGIN_USER:
   return {
    ...state,
    token: action.payload
   };
  case REGISTER_USER:
   return {
    ...state,
    users: [action.payload, ...state.users], 
    status: action.status
  };
 default:
  return state;
 }
}
```

Does it have something with fact that i didn't pass token in my authReducer?

Comment: is it working after you changed the state using the action in case of LOGIN_USER action ?

Comment: Nope, the usertoken goes into localstorage while after login action fires off i guess that's the problem why navbar is not being rendered.

Comment: @Wasilewski. what does the localStorage.setItem() returns. if this is the localStorage api that browser exposes, then it always returns ``undefined`` after setting the key-value pair in the local storage.

Comment: It returns key-value pair. Key: usertoken Value: jwt decoded value

Comment: can I know which library are you using for setting the localStorage ?

Comment: I am setting it via localStorage.setItem() function in axios HTTP post request

Comment: and does your ``Navbar`` component connected to the store or does it receive the ``userToken`` from any parent component. Because as far as I know, the best practice for a component to render something conditionally should be purely dependent on its state and not some outer factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is because your `Navbar` component is neither connected to the `Redux` store nor it receives the `userToken` as `props`. That is why when your reducer is updating your `state`, the `Navbar` is not getting re-rendered.
>
> Also it is always the best practice, to render anything based on either the `state` or `props`. Your `Navbar` component is checking directly in the localStorage for `rendering appropriate view`. Change it to something like below if you decide to pass the `userToken` as `props` to `Navbar` either from store or parent component.

```
return (
  <div className='navbar'>
    <ul className="navbar-navigation">
      <li className="navbar-navigation-item">
        <Link to='/' className='navbar-navigation-link'>
          Home
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    {this.props.usertoken ? profileLink : loginRegistrationLink}
  </div>
```

Comment: Everything is working fine after i connected my NavBar component to the store. Now i have problem with logout handler. It doesn't cause rerendering. Do i have to add new action (logoutUser) which will remove token for localstorage? And then pass it to reducer?

Comment: @D.Wasilewski. Can you update the code above please .

Comment: @D.Wasilewski. Again. to trigger re-rendering, you need to update the state. Your state is stored in the ``store``. So you need to update the store which will change the state. You ``mapDispatchToProps`` for that. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @D.Wasilewski. As I explained above, You need to update the state. read the comment. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I created new action "LogoutUser" that removes token from localStorage. Your answer was very helpfull. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the payload in your authreducer. Also, event.preventDefault() should be written before history.push('/') or you can write immediate after the function call.

Also, in your login Component, you should call the function like this-

```
this.props.dispatch(loginuser()) // pass the input params here 
this.props.history.push('/login')
```

You also need to connect your component with your redux store like below-

```
export default connect (mapStateToProps)(YourComp Name)
```

Comment: Did everything you said and it did not help

Comment: Updated my answer, check that out. I do not see you using mapStateToProps in your component.